# Javascript Date formatting shows incorrect hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

From the server I get a datetime serialized object. (`2016-11-03T10:51:01.517`)

When I do

```
var d = new Date("2016-11-03T10:51:01.517")
```

d is now 
`Thu Nov 03 2016 06:51:01 GMT-0400` (Eastern Daylight Time)

I need the time to be exactly `10:51:01`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a timezone error.

Comment: You mean it's a parsing error.

Comment: Not error. It is a normal behaviour of date parsing in JS. E.g., check what happens adding a "Z" after datetime string (`new Date( '2016-11-03T10:51:01.517Z' )`).

Comment: Yes, an error. "2016-11-03T10:51:01.517" **should** be parsed as local, but for the OP it's being parsed as UTC. "Normal behaviour" doesn't count, the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) does. If "normal" is what most browsers do, then it's not normal either. Firefox, Opera and Chrome get it right (local), Safari gets it wrong (UTC). As always: do not trust the built–in parser. ;-)

Comment: My testing browser is Firefox. In my first answer, when I said "error" I mean this is a bad assimilation of questioner. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can seeing the time in the local time zone format. Use **toUTCString()** method to get the time as you desired.

```
var d = new Date("2016-11-03T10:51:01.517")    
alert(d.toUTCString());
```

**d.toUTCString()** will return us `Thu, 03 Nov 2016 10:51:01 GMT`

Comment: Which is wrong. "2016-11-03T10:51:01.517" *should* be parsed as local as there is no timezone offset in the timestamp. The UTC equivalent should be different by the timezone offset, not the other way around. ;-)